# PHP - Aplicação Real Time

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb

Uma duvida

Preciso fazer uma aplicação que de tempos em tempos valide se uma sessão esta valida atraves de uma consulta ao banco.
Essa consulta deve ser feita de forma automática, sem a necessidade de uma acao do usuario, tipo um location.reload() do JS.

Pensei em usar um socket do php pra fazer essa validação, mas nao sei se e o caminho certo. Ou então mudar toda a ideia e abandonar o php e usar o nodeJs que parece ser mais util para esta funcionalidade.

Alguem poderia me explicar qual a melhor de forma de 
desenvolver esta aplicacao? Preciso apenas de um guia do que usar, e nao de codigos ou scripts prontos, é mais a questão conceitual mesmo e mostrar o caminho correto a seguir

Comment: De quanto em quanto tempo você vai fazer essa validação? Se for algo como <= cada 1 minuto eu consideraria o uso de sockets. Agora se digamos você quiser validar a cada 10 minutos eu ficaria com ajax.

Comment: Exatamente, 1 em 1 minuto seria o tempo ideal, pois tenho que validar se o usuario tem determinadas permissoes ainda validas no sistema, caso nao tenha irei redireciona-lo a uma pagina de login novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Segue o esboço abaixo em js e php.

Não vejo a necessidade de usar socket ou nodejs, quando uma simples requisição e um setInterval podem resolver seu problema.

Acada 5 segundos é chamado a função validaSessao(), que faz uma requisição ajax onde a mesma retorna uma array contendo o resultado de uma consulta sql;

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(validaSessao , 5000);
});
function validaSessao(){
    $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url: 'validaSessao.php',
        async: true,
         dataType:'json',
        success: function (retorno) {

            console.log(retorno);
        }


    });
}
```

PHP:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("");
$stmt->bindParam('', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$res = $stmt->execute();
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Não acredito ser o ideal consumir recursos de tempos em tempos dessa forma.